# Passive filters can provide gain

Tags: filter

I read in this book:

[image]

Why can’t passive filters provide a gain higher than 1. Isn’t that exactly what happens at the resonant peak of RLC filters ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, an LC filter just accumulates energy over multiple cycles at its resonant peak, causing the voltage across the filter's components to become higher than the input voltage. The power that can be extracted (continuously) from the filter will always be less than or equal to the power put into the filter.

You most likely confused "voltage gain" (which is what you were thinking of) with "power gain" (which is what the book is talking about). A passive circuit can very easily achieve significant voltage gain (or current gain) but it can never have power gain. A transformer is a very simple example of that. Mismatched transmission lines can also exhibit voltage gain due to reflections.

Comment: Ahhhh. The LC filter at resonance can give me a voltage gain, however the current will not also be increased. Hence power gain is constant. Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, I should say that the power gain is 1. No gain